# Angular JS rest get call request on page load example

Tags: angularjs

I am new one to AngularJS. I need to call http get method to reach nodejs before page load. Can anyone give me a sample example ??

**HTML :**

```
<body onLoad="loadData()>

</body>
```

**AngularJs :**

```
$scope.loadData =function($scope,http) {
// Need to know how to call the "/getcustomers" some url to hit the rest call here
//Already the route part is configured by someone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that might help;

```
$scope.loadData =function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('yourUrl/getCustomers').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.customers = data;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-init`

for example :

```
<body ng-init="loadData()">

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple angular app which sending http request on it loaded, please notice in angular app `onload` is barely used,

HTML:

```
<body ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'></body>
```

javascript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http){
         $scope.customers = [];

         $scope.loadData = function(){
              $http.get('rootUrl/getCustomers').then(function(data){
                   $scope.customers = data;
              })
         }

         //call loadData when controller initialized
         $scope.loadData();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use router(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngComponentRouter).
In route declaration you can set resolve object, which describes data, that you should get before move forward, by promises methodology.
You should do it like that:

```
resolve: {
    customers: function($http){ 
        return $http.get('/getCustomers');
    } 
}
```

and in controller dependency injection you can get it by name, that you determine in in a resolve object.
Do it this way, and you'll get your data before page starts rendering